# Magento 2 : Issue with Gift card price

Tags: magento2, product, multistore, catalog, gift-card

When i choose the UK store from UI Dropdown, i notice the gift cards display US currency rather that GBP.

I’m facing an strange issue on adding price amount base of store selection (US,UK,EU), on staging environment.

The issue is that when selecting gift card amount price in either US, UK or EU it doesn’t save the attribute for the gift card, so either of following options it wont save it after hit save button:

[image]

And also when re-open the gift product in admin it doesn’t show any price amount if they were added in above selection, so everything need to be at following selection:

[image]

Also it seems, when price saved in those selection (USD, EUR, GBP) somehow it save in db even thought it doesn’t show it in admin panel because I’ve seen it in multiple prices at front end.

[image]

Comment: any thoughts on this ?